# The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object>>

Tags: flutter, dart

could someone help with this issu . i am tring to solve this issu but i failed .please help me

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshots) {
                    if (snapshots.hasData) {
                      final messages = snapshots.data.docs;
                      List<Text> textwidgets = [];
                      for (var message in messages) {
                        final messageText = messages.data['text'];
                        final messageSender = messages.data['sender'];
                        final textwidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                        textwidgets.add(textwidget);
                      }
                      return Column(
                        children: textwidgets,
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you mistook `message` for `messages`

Try this:

```
for (var message in messages) {
  final messageText = message.data()['text'];
  final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
  final textwidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
  textwidgets.add(textwidget);
}
```