# The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object>

Tags: flutter, dart

could someone help me for these issu .i can't solve this .please help me

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshots) {
                    if (snapshots.hasData) {
                      final messages = snapshots.data.docs;
                      List<Text> textwidgets = [];
                      for (var message in messages) {
                        final messageText = messages.data['text'];
                        final messageSender = messages.data['sender'];
                        final textwidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                        textwidgets.add(textwidget);
                      }
                      return Column(
                        children: textwidgets,
                      );
```

Comment: Hey, you asked it elsewhere check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70875618/11452511

Answer (score 0):

The QuerySnapshot class has a docs property, which then return a List. You can then access an index from this List which gives you a QueryDocumentSnapshot that you can then acess its .data() method to have a Map<String, dynamic>. Finally you can access any field from that.

Try:

'snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['text'],
snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['sender']'